# Error in microsynth function "if (dum <= dum1 + 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r

Can anyone help me figure out why I get an error code with the `microsynth` function?

I *think* I have set up the data exactly as the tutorial describes, giving the ID variable, a time variable (which is numerical) and a binary treatment variable.

When I run the following code:

```
cov.var <- c("age", "sex", "ethgr2", "hh_size", "country_4", 
             "inc_imp", "nssec4", "ten1", "num_adult")
match.out <- c("ov_1", "ov_2", "ov_3", "ov_4")

synth1 <- microsynth(DS, 
                   idvar="seriali", timevar="year_2", intvar="treated", 
                   start.pre=1, end.pre=6, end.post=9, 
                   match.out=match.out, match.covar=cov.var, 
                   result.var=match.out, omnibus.var=match.out,
                   test="lower",
                   n.cores = min(parallel::detectCores(), 2))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in if (dum <= dum1 + 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

R doesn't provide a trackback to where an error occurred. Also, when looking at the source code for the function,  I can't see where I could supply a TRUE/FALSE.

I tried to follow the microsynth tutorial to see if I could reproduce the error. However, I get a different error.

```
data(seattledmi)
set.seed(99199)
cov.var <- c("TotalPop", "BLACK", "HISPANIC", "Males_1521", "HOUSEHOLDS", 
             "FAMILYHOUS", "FEMALE_HOU", "RENTER_HOU", "VACANT_HOU")
match.out <- c("i_felony", "i_misdemea", "i_drugs", "any_crime")
sea1 <- microsynth(seattledmi, 
                   idvar="ID", timevar="time", intvar="Intervention", 
                   start.pre=1, end.pre=12, end.post=16, 
                   match.out=match.out, match.covar=cov.var, 
                   result.var=match.out, omnibus.var=match.out,
                   test="lower",
                   n.cores = min(parallel::detectCores(), 2))
sea1
```

```
Error in colnames(newdat) : object 'newdat' not found
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I get the same error than you when I try the example. You should tell the developer about this issue on GitHub, maybe this will fix your error too, but maybe this package is still experimental. If you really want to debunk the problem you should try using `debug()` or `debugonce()`. This might help the developer even more.

Comment: Ah interesting, I will do. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have the same problem when I try to use my data set. I get this error and have no idea what it means. Even after converting my data to a `data.frame`

Answer (score 2):

After debugging the code, it seems that `microsynth` has some issues dealing with `tibble` objects; at least that's definitely where the second error comes from: The function `newreshape` attempts to run `time.tmp <- data[,timevar]`, which when applied to a tibble does not extract a vector (which then leads to issues further down) -- it should be e.g. `time.tmp <- dplyr::pull(data, timevar)`.

Even after fixing this though, there are still more errors, so I would simply try converting the data to a `data.frame` before running the code, which worked for me:

```
sea1 <- microsynth(as.data.frame(seattledmi), 
               idvar="ID", timevar="time", intvar="Intervention", 
               start.pre=1, end.pre=12, end.post=16, 
               match.out=match.out, match.covar=cov.var, 
               result.var=match.out, omnibus.var=match.out,
               test="lower",
               n.cores = min(parallel::detectCores(), 2))
```

Does this help?

Comment: While this works for this particular case the problem here is not only the class of the data, when I use my own data I get the same error despite it being a `data.frame`

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there are missing observations in your data. The following minimal code example produces the error using the `seattledmi` data set:

```
library(microsynth)

# Delete the fifth row of the seattledmi data set
mySeattledmi <- seattledmi[-c(5),]

# Define variables as in the microsynth tutorial
cov.var <- c("TotalPop", "BLACK", "HISPANIC", "Males_1521", "HOUSEHOLDS", 
             "FAMILYHOUS", "FEMALE_HOU", "RENTER_HOU", "VACANT_HOU")
match.out <- c("i_felony", "i_misdemea", "i_drugs", "any_crime")

# Run microsynth using the mySeattledmi data and all other parameters set equal to
# ... the values used in Example 1 of the microsynth tutorial
sea5 <- microsynth(mySeattledmi, 
                   idvar="ID", timevar="time", intvar="Intervention", 
                   start.pre=1, end.pre=12, end.post=16, 
                   match.out=match.out, match.covar=cov.var, 
                   result.var=match.out, omnibus.var=match.out,
                   test="lower",
                   n.cores = min(parallel::detectCores(), 2))
```

What is happening is that microsynth's newreshape function is creating (among other things) a matrix valued with the intvar column in your data. The matrix has dimensions n by t, where n equals the number of ids and t equals the number of time periods in your data, e.g. in the seattledmi data n = 9,642 and t = 16. If any observations are missing then this matrix will contain NAs. This leads to the value of `dum` in `if (dum <= dum1 + 1)` evaluating to `NA` and the error message.

One way to fix the problem is to eliminate any treatment or control groups that contain missing values. Continuing with the previous example, the following code deletes any observations from the `mySeattledmi` data that are associated with an ID that has less than 16 (i.e. `end.post - start.pre + 1`) observations.

```
library(dplyr)

nobsById <- mySeattledmi %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(nobs = n())
mySeattledmi2 <- mySeattledmi %>% subset(!(ID %in% nobsById[nobsById$nobs < 16, 1][[1]]))

# Call microsynth again this time with mySeattledmi2
sea6 <- microsynth(mySeattledmi2, 
                   idvar="ID", timevar="time", intvar="Intervention", 
                   start.pre=1, end.pre=12, end.post=16, 
                   match.out=match.out, match.covar=cov.var, 
                   result.var=match.out, omnibus.var=match.out,
                   test="lower",
                   n.cores = min(parallel::detectCores(), 2))
```