# Mycrosynth error because of missing values, but no missing values in the data set

Tags: r, missing-data

I have the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63359361/error-in-microsynth-function-if-dum-dum1-1-missing-value-where-true/76407509#76407509) with the `microsynth` function, with a different data set. I checked and there are no missing observations! Could there be a different way to solve this?

I tried checking with `is.na()` whether there were missing values, but there aren't any.

Comment: Please share some data and code to recreate your error - it makes it much easier for others to help. Can you also explain how your problem is different to the post you link to (other than a different data set), and why the solutions suggested there aren't working for you?